# Sharing encrypted file

Tags: android, cryptography, android-security

I'm using `ShareCompat` in my application. I'm downloading a file from the backend and then sharing it to other applications with
`.setStream(uriFileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), authority, file))`. Is it possible to share the encrypted file, for example using `EncryptedFile` because I don't want to store non-encrypted files on my device at any time?

Comment: `Is it possible to share the encrypted file,` Encrypted file? Where do you have an encrypted file? You only told you downloaded a file. You did not tell if it was encrypted or not.

Comment: Yes, I'm downloading it and need to save it somewhere to get Uri and I don't want to store the not encrypted file.